# Windows shares or rdp freezes

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008

I am having a problem accessing network files or using remote desktop to access server.

Environment:

Windows Server 2008 r2 --> for file sharing

Windows 7 --> client

Linux Mint --> client

The Windows Server 2008 is in the DMZ (ex: 192.168.x.x) and the clients are in another zone (ex: 10.0.x.x). The zones are separated by a Linux firewall.

Using Linux Mint, the shares on Windows Server or remote desktop work fine, but using Windows 7, I have these problems:

1. I am able to browse the share, but unable to open files
2. After some time, the share is no longer available, thus freezing "My Computer"
3. RDP asks for logins, but after a successful login, I get a black screen

I tested on Windows 8 and I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. It was related to the [While routing Kernel chokes on spurious "too big" IP packets](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=754294) bug.

Comment: So how did you solve it? Please provide an actual answer here, not just a link.